Fetch Single Table into Nested Pojo
I have the following database table:
catalog
- author
- book_name
- publication_date

Values in the catalog table look something like



author
book_name
publication_date




Mark Smith
How to Read
2024-01-01


Sarah Doe
A Book
1826-01-01


Sarah Doe
A Second Book
1855-07-15



I want to fetch the table into a Catalog POJO similar to this one:
public class Catalog {
    private String author;
    List < BookEntry > book_entries;
}

public class BookEntry {
    private String bookName;
    private Date publicationDate;
}

I have used the multiset (https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/multiset-value-constructor/) operator for doing similar things across separate tables, but I don't know if it is appropriate for this particular use-case.

The simplest way seems to be MULTISET_AGG(), in this case:
ctx.select(CATALOG.AUTHOR,
        multisetAgg(CATALOG.BOOK_NAME, CATALOG.PUBLICATION_DATE)
        .convertFrom(r -> r.map(Records.mapping(BookEntry::new))))
   .from(CATALOG)
   .groupBy(CATALOG.AUTHOR)
   .fetch(Records.mapping(Catalog::new))

Assuming you have the appropriate constructors on those classes, of course, and that you can handle the perils of not normalising this schema.

Unfortunately that is not supported in SQL Server

@Conner: Then you can achieve the same thing with a self-join and ordinary MULTISET usage. But at this point, why not just normalise the schema?

Unfortunately, the schema is out of my control. It is an extremely denormalized schema from an ERP. I'll go ahead and do the self-join.
